# Can't extract info from page using python requests and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract some info (latest news) from https://www.rtrs.tv/vijesti/index.php using python requests and beautiful soup and I encountered some problems. I don't have much experience in scraping but I would like to learn scraping with requests.

This is the piece of code that I am working on currently, and I am stuck here:

```
import requests

from requests import session

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link_root = r'https://www.rtrs.tv/vijesti/index.php'

with session() as c:

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

    r = c.get(link_root, headers=headers)

    print r

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    print soup
```

and I get this when printing (I took only part of data that is of my interest):
╨Æ╨╕╤ê╨║╨╛╨▓╨╕╤¢: ╨¥╨╕╤ü╨░╨╝ ╨┤╨╛╨▒╨╕╨╛ ╨╜╨╕╤ÿ╨╡╨┤╨░╨╜ ╨╖╨░╤à╤é╤ÿ╨╡╨▓ ╨╛╨┤ ╨£╨╕╨╗╨╕╤¢╨╡╨▓╨╕╤¢╨░

And something like this is expected: Папа позвао на потпуну забрану нуклеарног оружја (ФОТО/ВИДЕО)

So I was wondering, does it matters that site is using cyrilic or is there some other problem?

Does anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: maybe simply you don't have font with cyrilic to display it, or it is in different encoding then `UTF-8` and you get incorrectly encoded.

Comment: idk if this is what you are looking for or not. check my answer.

Comment: in case if you still having trouble with displaying the output. could you please advise which `IDLE` you are using ! and confirm if you are using `windows` ! also please inform if you run the script as `python script.py`.

Comment: also run this for me `import sys` and then `print(sys.stdin.encoding)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.rtrs.tv/vijesti/index.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'ul-najnovije'}):
    for new in item.findAll('li'):
        print(new.text)
```

output:

```
Вишковић: Нисам добио ниједан захтјев од Милићевића
БиХ не иде у НАТО; Српска враћена као фактор одлучивања (ФОТО) 
Драган Богданић реизабран за предсједника теслићког СНСД-а
Милиновић: РТРС уређују људи посвећени Српској
СИПА заплијенила 100 килограма дроге на подручју Требиња (ФОТО)
Тришић Бабић: Прича о члансту у НАТО стављена са стране
Додик за Раша тудеј: БиХ је неуспјешан експеримент Запада
Како је Шаровић удомио Пандуревићеву 
Девастирано Партизанско спомен-гробље у Мостару
Додик: СДС и ПДП хтјели да сједе у Сарајеву и наређују Српској (ВИДЕО)
Вулин: Угрожавањем безбједности Срба аутоматски угрожена и Србија
Вулин: Угрожавањем безбједности Срба аутоматски угрожена и Србија
Вулин: Угрожавањем безбједности Срба аутоматски угрожена и Србија
Путин честитао Кустурици рођендан (ФОТО)
Високи Дечани прославили ктиторску славу (ФОТО)
Србија остаје војно неутрална
Бреза: Мислили да је из Београда па му издували гуму и оставили поруку "Србине" (ФОТО)
Тихи одлазак Милана Дашића
Приједор: Завршена Друга балканска изложба ситних животиња (ФОТО)
Пас убацио аутомобил у рикверц и возио сат времена (ВИДЕО)
У малом Међувођу партизански авион пркоси времену
Бијељинац једини спасилац на води и под водом у зимским условима
У великом пожару у Сплиту петоро повријеђених (ФОТО/ВИДЕО)
Тужбу за Јасеновац упутити Суду у Стразбуру
Афера "Муниција": Павловић на слободи
Полиција разоружала тзв. Штајерску стражу (ФОТО)
Албанија отвара конзулат у Улцињу
У поплавама у Француској двоје несталих, поплављене стотине кућа (ФОТО)
Џонсон: Брегзит ће омогућити талас инвестиција
Најмоћнија икад забиљежена експлозија у свемиру (ВИДЕО)
"Пола свијета крвари због америчке похлепе"
Папа позвао на потпуну забрану нуклеарног оружја (ФОТО/ВИДЕО)
"Тесла" има скоро 150.000 наруџби за нови електрични камионет
Хаџићи једни од највећих произвођача мркве у Српској
Здрава храна адут средњег Подриња (ВИДЕО)
Више од 50 излагача на Аранђеловданском вашару (ФОТО)
Њемачки ауто-гигант повлачи 230.000 аутомобила
Билећа: Oдузето 6.700 паклица цигарета
Упао у кућу, претукао власника и украо 2.200 евра
Младић из Србије напао возача и претукао полицајце у Бечу
Пронађено тијело мушкарца у Сарајеву
МУП: Благић приведен јер је организовао јавни скуп без пријаве надлежном органу
"Српско благо из Беча и Вукова продаја српских реликвија" у Требињу
Позориште младих "Корфеј" из Нове Биле гостовало у Требињу
Бањалука: Отворена изложба о страдању југа Србије у Великом рату (ФОТО)
Промовисани 21. "Градишки зборник" и 22. зборник "Истина о Србима"
Филм "Четири руже" ускоро у кинима (ВИДЕО)
Соколац јутрос у минусу
У недјељу облачно уз краће сунчане интервале
Облачно уз дуже сунчане интервале
У суботу облачно са сунчаним интервалима
Сунчано уз умјерену облачност, температура до 18 степени
```

[image]